# Standalone modules with emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to use emscripten to build a side module for my JS app, so I don't need all the glue code it generates by default, and can provide the rest myself.

According to https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly-Standalone, most unnecessary dependencies will be removed automatically, and with `-fno-exceptions` C++ classes will not generate bloated exception handling.

However, using `malloc` (which is pretty hard to avoid) brings in several imports named `__syscall1`, etc. Why does it use such cryptic names and how do I find out what they're supposed to do?

I also considered using libc `malloc.c` but it depends on a lot of other standard libraries and cutting out all the dependencies from 5k+ lines is quite a chore.

**Edit:** realized that syscalls are equivalent to linux kernel syscalls, and their implementation is in [library_syscall.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_syscall.js). Altough the list seems incomplete - i.e. malloc calls syscall #45 (`brk`) but it is not in the list somehow.